# Principal ideal over a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

If we take the ring $k[x,y,z]/(xy-z^{2})$ and we  consider the ideal $I=(x,z)$, is  the image of $I$, in the ring $(k[x,y,z]/(xy-z^{2}))_{(x,y,z)}$ principal? Thank you for your time.

Comment: No, it is not principal.

Comment: Thank you @Mohan , but why?

Comment: I can´t see the point of your deduction, could you explain it to me please?

Comment: Show that $I/mI$ where $m=(x,y,z)$ is the maximal ideal, is a 2 dimensional vector space generated by $x,z$ and thus $I$ is generated by 2 elements, but not one element by Nakayama's lemma.

Comment: Did you calculate $mI$ as I said in my previous comment? Do you know Nakayama's lemma?

Comment: If $I$ were principal, $I/mI$ will also be generated by one element. Can you show that $x,y$ are linearly independent in $I/mI$ proving what you need?

Comment: Dear James, I am done. Please talk to your instructor if that is possible.